# SSIS Always Importing Files as ANSI Despite Setting Code Page

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

We're importing flat files through SSIS that I need to be imported as UTF-8 in order to allow correct encoding of special characters. I've set the code page to 65001 and the AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage setting to True. As a test, I've saved 2 copies of the same file using notepad. One where I set the encoding in the Save As dialog to ANSI, and the other to UTF-8.

When I import the UTF-8 file via SSIS, everything is fine. When I import the ANSI file via the same SSIS package, all the special characters are converted to `?`.

It seems like the code page settings aren't doing anything. How can I force files imported through SSIS to be encoded as UTF-8 every single time, regardless of what type of file they are?

I've seen a couple other questions related to exporting data to a flat file, but this is specifically related to importing data into SQL Server.

Comment: If you set the code page to `65001` and it's ANSI then the code page is wrong. It should be `1252`. If you are importing 2 different files, with different code pages, but not changing the code page in the package appropriately then yes, you're going to get wrong results. And That's exactly what's happening here.

Comment: I'm assuming I could use a script task to determine what the encoding type is on the file and then go down a different path based on that?

Comment: You *could* try something like that, however, I honestly think you;d be better off dealing with consistent code pages. If one is already going to be UTF-8 and another ANSI, then make sure you have 2 different connections that have the different code pages configured properly.

Comment: right, that's what I'm saying, I just mean we could use a script task to check the encoding, and then if it's ANSI then go down one path with a DFT configured with a separate connection manager for 1252, and then have a separate DFT for the UTF-8 files as well.

Comment: The question is, why if the file's code page being changed? Keep it consistent and you don't have a problem.

Comment: we get files from 100s of different companies coming from a variety of systems, so it's not surprising that they're not uniform. I'm surprised we haven't run into this previously.